# Enabling "Listen to this device" in Windows 7 via Java (and possibly Linux)

Tags: java, linux, windows, audio, javasound

Is it possible in Windows 7 to write a Java Application that can enable the "Listen to this device" setting on a microphone device?  I'm writing a radio application where when the user is transmitting they can hear "sidetone" but when they are not transmitting it is disabled.  Ultimately we would also want to do this on Linux but I suspect windows is going to be the more difficult task of the two.

Also would anyboyd be willing to provide any sample code if this is possible.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I suspect you are seeing that dialog on a lap-top/notebook/netbook with an **inbuilt** microphone.  I say that because I don't see any such dialog in Windows 7 on a desktop machine with mic. plugged in via USB.  And no, I doubt there is any way to achieve it in pure Java, on that machine, or any other.  It seems to be describing an audio loopback.  Some machines have it, others don't - and Java Sound just has to deal with what exists.

Comment: I can get this dialog with a USB mic plugged in.  Right click on volume and go to Recording Properties - then right click on your device and go to properties again and click on the listen tab

Answer (score 1):

A good first step is to get acquainted with the tools provided by the javax.sound.sampled library. The Java tutorial includes sample code for polling the various lines exposed by the OS. You can find this tutorial section at the following location:
[Accessing Audio System Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, that link does not actually answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding in Windows 7 onwards this functionality is locked into a private API and you will be unable to access it.